# Filter to-many related/child entities of NSManagedObject

Tags: cocoa, core-data, orm

I have an entity called **Playlist** which has a to-many relation with **Event** entity called *events*.

I also have **NSArrayController** configured in *Entity Mode* for managing **Playlist** entities

I need to *Pre Fetch* and filter events based on a criteria. The question is where exactly should I fetch events?

a. In Playlist's *awakeFromFetch*

b. In Playlist contoller's *fetchWithRequest*

c. Or is there a way to pre-fetch related entities based on a filter criteria?

Comment: If you've got access to the array controller object in interface builder (green cube in Interface Builder dock) it's possible that you won't have to do anything in code. Select the array controller in the dock, and in the *Attributes Inspector* check *Prepares Content*. You'll then need to go to the *Bindings Inspector* and hook up the array controllers *Managed Object Context* binding (probably use the App Delegate for this) this should be all you need to do to load in your *Playlist* entities when the xib loads.

Comment: I actually have 2 array controllers, one for playlist and other for events. The EventsController is bound to PlaylistController's selection.events property. The issue is that all events are loaded on fault and I want to fetch events based on a criteria. The bindings are ok I have no issues with that.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm not clear what you mean by prefetch, so sorry if I'm about to misunderstand you again, but could you bind somehow to the array controller's *Filter Predicate* binding, say to a ``filterPredicate`` property in one of your classes. If the predicate logic is simple, put it in a custom  ``filterPredicate`` getter, otherwise experiment with setting it wherever else make sense, e.g ``self.filterPredicate = ...``

Comment: I tried setting filterPredicate on EventsController but it does not seem to be working on ContentSet binding. For now I have configured EventsController in entity mode but not totally satisfied with it